# Amazon App Store Submission for a App which uses a self-signed certficate for SSL

Tags: android, https, ssl-certificate, self-signed, amazon-appstore

We are submitting an android app to Amazon app store, it was rejected once because our app wasn't using an secure connection for Sign-In/Sign-up requests.

Our concern is, if we use a **self-signed certificate** on server for HTTPS and use that server in our app, would that cause any issue with Amazon app store submission?

Would they require our SSL certificate to be **signed by a valid CA**?

Comment: Looks like no-one has encountered such scenario here. I have submitted the app, and will revert back with the results here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our app was successfully submitted with a few cycles of Bug resolving. Those were other issues not related to this.

My point is that **you can use SSL with a self-signed certificate for submission on Amazon App store**.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have more experience than me with the store, but Amazon's policy ("https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html#Submitting Apps Binary Info") says you have to sign with their certificate or contact them directly:

All applications must be digitally signed with a certificate. The default signature applied to your app is a certificate supplied by Amazon that is unique to your developer account. If your signing strategy requires that a different certificate be applied, you may do so by submitting a request via the "Questions about application signatures" subject in the Contact Us section of the Amazon Appstore Developer Portal. Please indicate the title of the application for which you are submitting the request.

---

I'm now trying to figure out where that app is, but that's another story.

Comment: I was asking about SSL certificate, not the app certificate. Though, I have got answer to my queries, and will post it here.